# InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid Error when tried to fetch image from url

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I am trying to fetch a image texture from

```
IEnumerator GetRequest1(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        img = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture;      
    }
}
```

and passing it to a GUI

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(100, 50, 500, 500));
    GUILayout.Label(img);
    GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

on it should have worked previous days it was, today with some modifications its hitting error ,[tried this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-bug-invalidcastexception-specified-cast-is-not-valid.710021/)  and much more, but could not get helped. It would be great if I get a hint. thank you

i am using same method somewere else but thats perfect , in here its hitting error as

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>   gettiles+d__25.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/gettiles.cs:111)UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)

an InvalidCastException error Hits in case where the actual type of the data doesn't match the type which was passed But here it is sprite to sprite

> specificimage.sprite = Sprite.Create(((DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture, new Rect(0, 0, 250,250).texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));

Comment: what type is img variable?

Comment: Texture2D img;   ofCourse,

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: try to use ``UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url)``

Comment: i am using this currently

Comment: @akhilesh no it doesn't seem so ... you are using `UnityWebRequest.Get` in your code snippet

Comment: Is there also a specific reason to use `OnGUI` which is kind of legacy for ages by now? Rather use the [UI System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(uri))
{
       yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

       if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
       {
           Debug.Log(uwr.error);
       }
       else
       {
           img =  DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
           specificimage.sprite =Sprite.Create(img, new Rect(0, 0, img.width, img.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
       }
}
```

Comment: where is the error? here? img =  DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr); can you paste the error, please?

Comment: Question updated , but at line Gettiles.Cs:111  -- specificimage.sprite = Sprite.Create(((DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture, new Rect(0, 0, 250, 250), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
            }   which has nothing to do,,
!

Comment: don't use (DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture

use instead "img" created before

Comment: didnt get you sir,,

Comment: When you create the sprite with : Sprite.Create(((DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture, new Rect(0, 0, 250,250).texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
There error is in (DownloadHandlerTexture)webRequest.downloadHandler).texture. You need to use the form that I used in the answer. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: @akhilesh well according to your own answer attempt the URL was **NOT** good! You should accept this answer here

Comment: @G.Threepwood you should maybe use `new Rect(0, 0, img.width, img.height)` instead unless the `250` was specifically introduced by OP

Comment: yes sir @derHugo the url response was not good, i didnt mean to ignore that sorry.

Comment: @derHugo yes, I pasted a script from my project and I forgot to change that. I edit the answer

Answer (score -1):

Problem was not with 
   **DownloadHandlerTexture**
  problem was the image i was getting **"TileFusion1".png** insted i should get **TileFusion1.png**
 simple but irritating one, **HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden** was hitting because of this